# Why am I getting a different result when I run this mean in a slightly different way?

Tags: r, conditional-statements, mean

In the first block of code, I am grouping by `VAR1` and I get a mean for `VAR2` based on the two categories of `VAR1`. However, when I select only for the category of interest from `VAR1`, in order to obtain a mean of people for `VAR2` who fall into `category 1 in VAR1`, I get a different result.

What am I doing wrong?

```
 DF %>%
   na.omit() %>%
   group_by(VAR1) %>% 
   summarise(mean(VAR2))

# A tibble: 2 × 2
  VAR1 `mean(VAR2)`
                     <dbl>                         <dbl>
1                        0                          12.1
2                        1                          11.6

> mean(DF[DF$VAR1 == 1, 'VAR2',],na.rm=TRUE)

[1] 11.95238
```

Comment: `na.omit` first will remove the whole row if there's an `NA` value, not just the `NA` value in the column.

Comment: Adding on to @thelatemail's explanation:  DF must have other variables in it with NAs.  When you run `na.omit()` you are losing rows relevant to the current calculation because, e.g., VAR3 has a bunch of NAs in it.

Comment: And, in the second mean? What NA is being removed?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). It's easier to answer questions when you provide some data. You can provide your data via the output of `dput(DF)` or to give a minimal subset use `dput(head(DF))`.

Answer (score 1):

The discrepancy in the mean values of `VAR1` in those cases probably comes from the presence of NAs in another column, as @DanY explained briefly. I will try to elaborate this through the following example. Suppose we have DF that consists of three columns, two of which come from `mtcars` and another one is `VAR1`. Suppose there are 15 rows with `VAR1` of `0`.

```
library(dplyr) 
DF <- mtcars %>% select(mpg, cyl)
DF$VAR1 <- c(rep(0, 15),rep(1,17))
DF
#                     mpg cyl VAR1
#Mazda RX4           21.0   6    0
#Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6    0
#Datsun 710          22.8   4    0
#Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6    0
#Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8    0
#Valiant             18.1   6    0
#Duster 360          14.3   8    0
#Merc 240D           24.4   4    0
#Merc 230            22.8   4    0
#Merc 280            19.2   6    0
#Merc 280C           17.8   6    0
#Merc 450SE          16.4   8    0
#Merc 450SL          17.3   8    0
#Merc 450SLC         15.2   8    0
#Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8    0
#Lincoln Continental 10.4   8    1
#Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8    1
#Fiat 128            32.4   4    1
#Honda Civic         30.4   4    1
#Toyota Corolla      33.9   4    1
#Toyota Corona       21.5   4    1
#Dodge Challenger    15.5   8    1
#AMC Javelin         15.2   8    1
#Camaro Z28          13.3   8    1
#Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8    1
#Fiat X1-9           27.3   4    1
#Porsche 914-2       26.0   4    1
#Lotus Europa        30.4   4    1
#Ford Pantera L      15.8   8    1
#Ferrari Dino        19.7   6    1
#Maserati Bora       15.0   8    1
#Volvo 142E          21.4   4    1
```

Now, let's change three values of `cyl` into `NA`.

```
DF$cyl[3:5] <- NA
head(DF)
#                   mpg cyl VAR1
#Mazda RX4         21.0   6    0
#Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6    0
#Datsun 710        22.8  NA    0
#Hornet 4 Drive    21.4  NA    0
#Hornet Sportabout 18.7  NA    0
#Valiant           18.1   6    0
```

Now `DF` still have 15 values of `mpg` with `VAR1` of `0` because neither `mpg` nor `VAR1` has `NA`. Now we try to compare the mean of `mpg` in the two cases you have compared:

```
DF %>% na.omit() %>% group_by(VAR1) %>% summarise(mean(mpg))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#   VAR1 `mean(mpg)`
#  <dbl>       <dbl>
#1     0        18.2
#2     1        21.3

mean(DF[DF$VAR1 == 0, 'mpg',], na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 18.72
mean(DF[DF$VAR1 == 1, 'mpg',], na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 21.3
```

Clearly you got different mean values. It is because in `DF %>% na.omit()` operates on `DF` so any NA value in any row in `DF` will cause omission of that row. That's why the three rows in `cyl` that contain `NA`s are omitted so that `mpg` column has only 12 values, of which the mean is then computed.

```
DF %>% na.omit()
#                     mpg cyl VAR1
#Mazda RX4           21.0   6    0
#Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6    0
#Valiant             18.1   6    0
#Duster 360          14.3   8    0
#Merc 240D           24.4   4    0
#Merc 230            22.8   4    0
#Merc 280            19.2   6    0
#Merc 280C           17.8   6    0
#Merc 450SE          16.4   8    0
#Merc 450SL          17.3   8    0
#Merc 450SLC         15.2   8    0
#Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8    0
#Lincoln Continental 10.4   8    1
#Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8    1
#Fiat 128            32.4   4    1
#Honda Civic         30.4   4    1
#Toyota Corolla      33.9   4    1
#Toyota Corona       21.5   4    1
#Dodge Challenger    15.5   8    1
#AMC Javelin         15.2   8    1
#Camaro Z28          13.3   8    1
#Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8    1
#Fiat X1-9           27.3   4    1
#Porsche 914-2       26.0   4    1
#Lotus Europa        30.4   4    1
#Ford Pantera L      15.8   8    1
#Ferrari Dino        19.7   6    1
#Maserati Bora       15.0   8    1
#Volvo 142E          21.4   4    1

DF %>% na.omit() %>% filter(VAR1 == 0) %>% pull(mpg) %>% mean
# [1] 18.15833
```

On the other hand, `DF[DF$VAR1 == 0, 'mpg',]` operates only on `mpg` column, and has nothing to do with `cyl`. That's why it has 15 values of `mpg` with no `NA` so `na.rm` will not omit anything.

```
DF[DF$VAR1 == 0, 'mpg',]
#[1] 21.0 21.0 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 17.8 16.4
#[13] 17.3 15.2 10.4

mean(DF[DF$VAR1 == 0, 'mpg',], na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 18.72
```